# How to expire the session at button click in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have a aspx page having 2 textboxes for username and password.At submit button click,it is getting redirect to another page.This page has 2 buttons named "Expire Session" and "Go to profile Page". Now clicking on second button gets the user to another page where he can see the content of this page.I want when the user click expire session button,the session should be expired and then when user will click on the "Go to profile Page" button,he will be redirected to page but no content will be visible because session is over now. 
This is Submit button coding .

```
 protected void clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["username"] = textbox_username.Text.ToString();
        Session["password"] = textbox_password.Text.ToString();
        message.Text = "Session saved!";
        textbox_username.Text = null;
        textbox_password.Text = null;
        Response.Redirect("SessionTest.aspx");
    }
```

I do not know how to expire the session at "Expire Session" button click.I am a newbie.

Comment: I recommend you to not store password in session ... quite dangerous, prefer store username only

Comment: Have you tried anything to clear your session? Your question seems a bit lazy. It would have taken you 30 seconds to Google that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer for short question :

```
//Destroys the session
Session.Clear();
Session.Abandon();
Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
```

Use `Session.Clear();` before above code, if you want to clean session values, but with a `Session.Abandon();` you will destroy it.

Check session with

```
if(Session["username"] == null) { }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try with this code

```
    Session.Clear();
    Session.Abandon();
    //FormsAuthentication.SignOut(); // If you are using FormsAuthentication
    Response.Redirect("Your.aspx");
```

You can check here

```
if(Session["username"] == null)
{
...
}
```

Comment: then how could i check at "Go to profile page" button click,if the session has been expired or not.I mean if it has been expired,user won't see any content of that page and vice versa.
Thanks

Comment: if(Session["username"] == null){...}    happy to help you

Comment: but it throws the exception when i tried it.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: if condition throws exception

Comment: Try to see value of Session["username"] while debugging

Comment: Not in pageload.
Well i was doing like so that it was giving the exception.
if(Session["usrename"].Equals(Null))
I changed it to like below and it is working fine.
if(Session["usrename"]==null)
Both mean didn't same?

Comment: @Asp_Newbie I'am happy that you solved your problem, it's not same, because Equals Method requires instance of object

Answer (score 1):

You won't when you click on "Expire Session" button then all your session should be expire

So you can use below function in your button click event :

```
 protected void btnExpireSession_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Session.Abandon();
 }
```

I think this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

`Session.Abandon()` to destroys the session. This can probably be used when user logs out.
`Session.Clear()` just removes all values (content) from the Object.